# android found tag ... where item is expected

Tags: android

I'm working on a project that has a custom XML file in the res/values map.

It's not a deep XML:

```
<resources>
    <accesspoint
    ...
```

Eclipse is generating an error: `found tag accesspoint where item is expected`

Now, I've googled this a bit and there are similar problems everywhere. But no solution.
When I change them all to item and give them a name and a type, I still get an error on the closing tags that simply says "Orginally defind here".

I'm out of ideas here, does anyone know what this means? And how I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

Something is a bit screwy in Eclipse.  I had the same problem as you no matter what I renamed the tag.

**Solution:**  delete the tag, and re-write it by hand (DON'T COPY/PASTE).

There must be some kind of strange hidden character that gets in there somehow, because just re-writing the EXACT same thing, and I now have no errors.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the xml file in the package explorer, then Source -> Format.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a 9 years old question. But I got the same error message today. My solution differs from the described answers. Changes in the - here - corresponding file `accesspoints.xml` were necessary. My corresponding content was:

```
<resources>
    <accesspoint name="btnOpen">false</accesspoint>
    ...
</resources>
```

This `accesspoint` tag is to be replaced by the `item` tag:

```
<resources>
    <item type="accesspoint" name="btnOpen">false</item>
    ...
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried all of the above solutions. None of them worked. Found the problem in Eclipse:

Copy the xml file from res/values folder to res/xml folder.

Comment: This worked for me , I had created xml file and placed it in values, but in manifest it was `android:resource="@xml/file_name"`

Answer (score 0):

Running the xml source file through xmllint is a good way to pick up otherwise non-visible special characters. In particular keep an eye out non-breakable space (&nbsp;/&#160;/&#xa0;) which can cause cryptic errors if they occur where the ADK tools are expecting whitespace.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the OP's problem and xmllint does not detect it, but Dave's solution (workaround, actually) solves it.

Answer (score 0):

open the xml file with MadEdit or any other Hex File editors, look for "C2 A0" and replace all with normal space.

Or simply in the command line

$sed -i 's/\xc2\xa0/ /g' /the/path/to/the/xml/file

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this error. Probably these issues are arising due to simple mistakes.

Those can be

1. Invalid characters in the string value. Remove unsupported characters and check.
2. When we copy/paste from some other places, there can be possible of having hidden/unnoticed invalid characters, so check for that and remove those.

Advice :
Instead of copying/pasting, type by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes Eclipse goes crazy.

Paste your code in Notepad and then copy it from Notepad and paste it to Eclipse.